# Multiple phone numbers of the same type & Exchange

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, exchange

My company's directory uses the "Business" field to list the internal extension, and the "Business 2" field to list the fully qualified phone number. Obviously my cell phone cannot call the internal extension.

"Business" shows up in my phone as "Work", and "Mobile" shows up too, but "Business 2" does not seem to appear. Now, my phone is pretty new to me so it could be I'm not navigating People correctly.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Moto G, KitKat. I think I am sync'ing against Exchange 2007 or Exchange 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the custom fields are synched to the device, the inbuilt contact managers can unfortunately not view, or edit them. I experienced a similar problem on my HTC One.

Comment: Well that is incredibly disappointing. Can People be updated as a module, if for example I was able to add support? Or is modifying/improving the core software prohibitively difficult.